# What are these yellow, eight-petal flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

What are these yellow flowers? There are currently lots and lots of them (here in Central Europe, zone 6), mostly in the shade of large trees in a park environment. The flowers are approx. 2 cm in diameter. A lot of purple [liverworts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_hepatica) grew in the same environment, but those have mostly withered by now.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like [lesser celandine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_celandine), which belongs to the buttercup family, as does the The purple liverworts you mentioned.

Comment: Definetively correct, have been battling these for decades... You might want to mention that the buds and young leaves are edible (before flowers open).